# How to automatically pull Steam statistics from a specific game into Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, steam, steam-web-api

For example I've tried this and it works fine. But the problem I have with this one is that it loads my entire Steam library of around 2700 items. I can't seem to find anything or figure out how to get statistics from just one specific game like the name or amount of hours I've played.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=STEAMAPIKEYHERE&steamid=STEAMIDHERE&format=xml&include_appinfo=1"; "//response/games/message/name")
```

Comment: Please add some sample input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Hi, The [Link](https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=STEAMAPIKEYHERE&steamid=STEAMIDHERE&format=xml&include_appinfo=1) is Unauthorized to everyone but the owner "You" , make sure to mention that in the question.